# Insert statement with CodeIgniter -- so confused

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm doing well with CodeIgniter. I can do SELECT statements on my MySQL database with no problems at all. But, now I'm trying to do an INSERT statement.

Note that I have not tried an UPDATE statement yet.

After reading the docs, I'm so confused.

This is what I have:

contacts.php:

```
function add() {

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);

    $this->load->model('Contacts_model');
    $this->Contacts_model->insertContact($_POST);
}
```

contacts_model.php:

```
function insertContact($_POST) {

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
    $title = $_POST['title']; // I can echo this here. It works
    $f_name = $_POST['f_name']; // I can echo this here. It works



    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (title,f_name) " .
        "VALUES (" .
        $this->db->escape($title) .
        "," .
        $this->db->escape($f_name) .
        ")";
    $this->$db->query($sql);
}
```

I've read about Active Record, but if that's what is messing me up, then I still don't realize what I'm doing wrong. All of the examples look exactly like mine.

Help?

**EDIT**

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (title,f_name) VALUES ('$this->db->escape($title)','$this->db->escape($f_name)'";
    $this->$db->query($sql);
```

I've also tried it like this. And many other variants. It doesn't seem to be my syntax... I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is fine, only reason that why query is not being executed is that you are using this:

```
$this->$db->query($sql);
```

there is nothing like $db, just use this:

```
$this->db->query($sql);
```

I'm sure this is the problem, but if it is not then please kindly post the error what it is giving. Thanks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I could kick myself. I got so wrapped up with other harder parts of this framework that I didn't even notice a stupid typo like that! 

Thank you so much!

Comment: also check for `$id = $this->db->insert_id(); if($id>0){ //successfull entry} else{//unsuccessfull entry}`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the quote character:

```
$title = $this->db->escape($title);
$fname = $this->db->escape($f_name)
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (title,f_name) " .
    "VALUES ('{$title}', '{$fname}')";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

BTW, What the hell with the `$_POST` variable? It's one of [SuperGlobal variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). You don't have to transfer it in parameter. You can always safely call it anywhere in your script.

Another note, since you use CodeIgniter, you better check out the [`Input` class library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) and use it for all your input need.

Comment: The $_POST variable is just so I can insert data to see if I can insert data. Now that I can (because the $db typo is fixed), I'm moving on to filtering my input and doing it properly. 

I will check out the class library for Input immediately :) Thank you for the help!

Comment: MAn thats not his problem, dont tell him to use $this->$db->query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

```
Why send $_POST? Use $this->input->post("param_name") and in your instance "$this->load->model('Contacts_model');" in my practice i use "$this->load->model('Contacts_model','instance',[true or false]);" the last parameter is optional (to connect with the DB if you don't use autoload option).

Use this:

function insertContact() {
    $title = $this->input->post("title");
    $f_name = $this->input->post("f_name");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (title,f_name) " .
        "VALUES ('" . $this->db->escape($title) . "','".$this->db->escape($f_name) ."')";
    $this->$db->query($sql);
}


DON'T USE $_POST! (And use the Active Record read the user guide)
```